# Entire streamed video is not playing using VideoView

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have the following code for playing a video from a Uri:

```
final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/star_trails.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading video.....");
        progressDialog.show();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                mediaController.show();
            }
        });
```

The first 7 seconds of the video play, however the video then pauses. The remaining video is buffered, When I seek to another point in the video it will play for another few seconds.

Comment: Do you have any view ontop of videoview in your layout? This prob is the problem

Comment: The videoView is simply contained in a Fragment layout. The activity is launched from another activity as a new Intent.